# Emailing a PDF from AbstractPdfView in Java

Tags: java, spring, email, pdf, itext

I use the AbstractPdfView class to generate a pdf and download in the browser but I also need to email it. I know the solution is very obvious, but i've been stuck on this for a day now and cannot get see it. Here what i have so far:

```
@GetMapping()
public PdfView generate(Model model, @RequestParam int event) {

  model.addAttribute("event", eventService.getEventById(event));

  return new PdfView();


}
```

That is the PdfView class:

```
public class PdfView extends AbstractPdfView {

   @Override
   protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        //add the iformation for the pdf
        document.add(getInvoiceInfo());

   }
}
```

And that is the AbstractPdfView class:

```
public abstract class AbstractPdfView extends AbstractView {

   public AbstractPdfView() {
      setContentType("application/pdf");
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean generatesDownloadContent() {
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   protected final void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

  ByteArrayOutputStream out = createTemporaryOutputStream();

  Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 35, 35, 50, 36);
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
  prepareWriter(model, writer, request);
  buildPdfMetadata(model, document, request);

  document.open();
  buildPdfDocument(model, document, writer, request, response);
  document.close();

    //i know i has to happen before this bit here but not sure how
   writeToResponse(response, out);

}

   protected void prepareWriter(Map<String, Object> model, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request) throws DocumentException {
      writer.setViewerPreferences(getViewerPreferences());
   }

   protected int getViewerPreferences() {
      return PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.PageLayoutSinglePage;
   }


   protected void buildPdfMetadata(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, HttpServletRequest request) {
   }

   protected abstract void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, PdfWriter writer,
                                            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception;
}
```

Any help is welcomed! Thank you guys.

Comment: which pdf library are you using?

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention that. It's iText.

Comment: Refer this https://javakapil.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/how-to-send-pdf-via-email-generated-from-itext/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've gone ahead and done it. Posting it here if someone ever encounters this. I basically autowired the emailService in the implementation of the AbstractPdfView, calling the constructor of the abstract class with it. Also here is a good read on the subject: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowired-abstract-class